# WFFM - Accessing function inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using Web Form For Marketers (WFFM) and I have created a couple of custom functions inside $scw.widget object, in wffm.js. The problem is when calling one of that functions OUTSIDE the object, I get "function is not defined".

Example:

```
$scw.widget("wffm.track", {
    options: {
         formId: null,
         fieldId: null,
         fieldTitle: null,
         fieldValue: null,
         eventCount: null,
         rules: null
    },
    //Custom function
    checkRequiredFields: function (e, element) {
         var form = $scw(element).closest("form");
         if ($scw(form).find(".form-group.required-field.valid").length === $scw(form).find(".form-group.required-field").length) {
            if ($scw(form).parents("#c-fab__brochure").length) {
                if ($scw(form).parents("#c-fab__brochure").find(".brochure-cover").attr("data-selected") === "true") {
                    this.validForm(e, form);
                }

            } else {
                  this.validForm(e, form);
            }
        } 
    },
});
```

And I have tried this:

```
$scw(".parent")
     .off("click.scw")
     .on("click.scw", ".child", function (e) {
           $scw.widget.checkRequiredFields(e, $scw(".child").parents(".main-parent").find("form"));
});
```

Then I get:

```
$scw.widget.checkRequiredFields is not a function
```

What's the proper way to access the function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$scw is just certain version of jQuery that is used to avoid conflicts with few versions of jQuery on your site. (as WFFM require a specific one and your site could require another).

Knowing that $scw is just jQuery I can suggest you to use jQuery approach:

```
$scw(".child").track("checkRequiredFields", e, ".child");
```

If it doesn't help, try to look for how to call methods jQuery widgets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Anton. I finally solved it in a different way, calling the method from the _create method. Definitely I have to look how to call these methods.